# Python .decode function

Tags: python, python-2.7

What are the strings that python can decode?

```
hi = "647361647361"
lolly = hi.decode("hex")
print lolly
```

What are other .decode functions that are present in python? other than ("hex")? is there a full list?

Comment: You really should use google....https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings

Comment: Be aware that Python 3 changes things greatly. Don't get used to doing things in a way that won't be supported later.

Comment: `hi.decode("hex")` could be written more durably as `binascii.unhexlify(hi)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The full list for python 2.7.x is [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings) in 7.8.3 and 7.8.4